# rake db:migrate - Rake aborted! Access denied

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rubygems

I have tried for the past 6 hours surfing the web bt nothing works. This deploy used to work fine now i cant get past this step.

when I try and rake db:migrate or seed i get the following error

```
    rake aborted!
Access Denied
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/aws-sdk-1.25.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:366:in `return_or_raise'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/aws-sdk-1.25.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:467:in `client_request'
(eval):3:in `get_object'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/aws-sdk-1.25.0/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:1330:in `get_object'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/aws-sdk-1.25.0/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:1076:in `read'
/Users/Robert/wordyarn-web/app/helpers/error_logger.rb:26:in `initialize_notification_preferences'
/Users/Robert/wordyarn-web/config/initializers/error_notifications.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/Robert/wordyarn-web/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I cant get it to work no matter what

here is the database-local.yml file

```
  development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: wordyarn_development
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  #port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: wordyarn_test
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  #port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: wordyarn_development
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  #port: 3306
```

Comment: this is a shot in the dark but do you have any aws-related code getting loaded in your initializer?

Comment: @sylv3rblade    Where can I check this? (its been 7 months since i done this stuff but used to work fine back then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can find the configuration of as in `config/initializer/aws.rb`
- It seems that you have an access error, please make sure the following things are correct:

  - access_key_id
  - secret_access_key

Comment: Looks like I deleted the access key in AWS. That is a problem i will need to fix but i didn't think it would effect a local DB migration or seed from happening. Or does it grab the DB info from AWS? (Yet to test if it fixed it but curious to know to grow knowledge)

Comment: Oh God it worked! Now to run into a million other silly problems to get a deploy out that i haven't deployed in a long time

Comment: Glad to know that. Best of the luck for the rest.